# Pass javascript function from .Net code behind shared function or web method to page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, scriptmanager

I need to send a script to the page from WebMethod used by Ajax that fires when click HTML link. I couldn't use the script manager with "Me" or "Page" control and can't reference any controls.

**I just need to return that session is nothing** , Any Ideas?

The button clicked to send Ajax is HTML link and all I need to check if session expired (which I can check it on load) so if it's expired want to alert user since I already don't complete the process  after checking it in code behind

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Send(ByVal data As String) As String

    If Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MemberID") Is Nothing Then

            Try

               ''''' my code
               ''''''''''''''''''''''

            If Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MemberID") Is Nothing Then
                Return "Success"
            Else
                Return "noSession"

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return "failure"

        End Try
    Else
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "Checkeng", [String].Format("LevelsMsg();"), True)
    End If

End Function
```

## JQuery Ajax

It's more complecated but I thinkk this is the main part:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Add", function() {
        var _fulldata = $('#basket').html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'Order.aspx/SendOrder',
            data: "{'fulldata':'" + _fulldata + "'}",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("There is a problem in saving data");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: can you show me your javascript? The part where you call your WebMethod from? We can make changes to it and you can force your WebMethod to return to JavaScript domain then from that point you can make it call any javascript function..

Comment: I have added the main part .. many other functions are attached

Comment: From your JQuery I don't see where you call WebMethod Send?

Comment: It's only a shared function on url : 'Order.aspx/SendOrder',

Comment: the button clicked to send Ajax is HTML link and all I need to check if session expired (which I can check it on load) so if it's expired want to alert user since I already don't complete the process  after checking it in code behind

Comment: In your WebMethod, instead of using ScriptManager, why don't you redirect to another page? OR instead of using ScriptManager, you should return "Success2" then in your success: function(response) {} you can check the response and then call another JavaScript function like LevelsMsg()?

Comment: I tried return "success" if session and return "noSession" if not and tried on success case but something not going well

Comment: Can you alert(response) and see what you get?

Comment: When alert response get [object Object] and if tried to use if (response = "noSession") {alert(response);} it returnes "noSession" or success when use success

Comment: you should do: if (response == "noSession")

Comment: Wait so if you get noSession then thats good right? You can call LevelsMsg()?

Comment: I used if (response == "Success") to make sure but it doesn't alert any .. any way yes if got no session whenever there is no session I can alert or call function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WebMethod`is a `Shared` function which is equivalent to a `Static` function in C#. This means you will not be able to access any variables other than those declared inside of this `Shared` function. However, the nature of `WebMethods` allow a return to "its" caller via "Success"  or "error" which can be "intercepted". Thus, no need to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` since your POST will return to AJAX realm anyway, which means you can call any JavaScript function there.

You could Change your code this way:

**VB.NET Code-Behind:**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Send(ByVal data As String) As String
    If Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MemberID") Is Nothing Then
        Try
            ' YOUR CODE        
            Return "Success"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "Failure"
        End Try
    Else
        Return "NoSession";
    End If
End Function
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#Add", function() {
    var _fulldata = $('#basket').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Order.aspx/SendOrder',
        data: "{'fulldata':'" + _fulldata + "'}",
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            /* since we put "NoSession", then we should check for it here */
            if(response.d == "NoSession") {
                /* This is where you "replace" the use of RegisterStartupScript 
                   by safely calling any JS function here */
                LevelsMsg();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("There is a problem in saving data");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code .. I still don't get the right response value .. it doesn't call the function or even alert on both if =success or = noSession as well it returns a value of [object Object] when try alert(response)

Comment: if you put a debug point on If Not System.Web.HttpContext, does it get hit?

Comment: it works since the page don't apply my main code which add to database and send mail which placed before return "response"

Comment: I log in, make an order, it goes to database and customer and admin mail then I logout from different page and then try re-add the order and it doesn't go anywhere because the code and server side check but can't do it in client side

Comment: instead of: if(response== "NoSession") change it to: if (response.d=="NoSession"), I updated the answer as well. First try: alert(response.d) and see what you get?

Comment: Oh .. I have read this before .. 4 days maybe .. brain fart :).. I think you are right .. willl back to u in min

Comment: Lets hope thats the problem :) You are getting [Object Object] because its an object NOT a string, so you need to access the data part of that object by using .d

Comment: sweeeet .. worked and called the function and redirect and able to add whatever , modal, alert any :) glad .. thanks

Comment: I used if = success .. else  .. for some reason it couldn't know if = noSession maybe because it's out of "try "

Comment: thats because Return "Success" happnes before Return "NoSuccess", thats why you dont get "NoSuccess", but you might?

Comment: I will work on it but it's not that important in my case .. look to my nested "if else" in VB code I think it might help

Comment: Sorry, had to tell you .. it worked as it I was calling the wrong function which was not updated with your "NoSession" case . your code is fine till end